# Linq groupby list matching and count

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have a line of json that I deserialize and create a list of lists:

```
var json = @"[{'names': ['a','b']} ,{'names': ['z','y','j']} ,{'names': 
['a','b']}]";
var json_converted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
var namelist = json_converted
```

I want to use linq to compare the list contents and see if the items in the list match another list

ex)

names............matching list count

List {a,b}    =          2

List {z,y,j}  =          1

I've tried the following, but no dice    :/

```
 var namelist = json_converted
 .GroupBy(n => n.names)
 .Select(i => new { name = i.Key, Count = i.Count() });
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by a `string` produced from your list items taken in the same order. Assuming that `'|'` character is not allowed inside names, you can do this:

```
var namelist = json_converted
    .GroupBy(n => string.Join("|", n.names.OrderBy(s => s)))
    .Select(g => new {
        Name = g.First().names
    ,   Count = g.Count()
    });
```

This approach constructs a string `"a|b"` from lists `["a", "b"]` and `["b", "a"]`, and use that string for grouping the content.

Since the keys are composed of ordered names, `g.First().names` used as `Name` may not be in the same order for all elements of the group.

Comment: Thanks !  Just what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a comparer for the list of names.

```
public class NamesComparer : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<string>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<string> x, IEnumerable<string> y)
    {
        //do your null checks
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<string> obj)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then use that in GroupBy:

```
var namelist = json_converted.GroupBy(n => n.names, new NamesComparer())
                             .Select(i => new { name = i.Key, Count = i.Count() });
```